# AngularJS directive transclude scope=false?

Tags: javascript, html, binding, angularjs

How to prevent directive with transclude to create new scopes?

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHLzK/) I cant bind anything due to the new scopes illustrated with red borders.

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app="components">
    <input ng-model="var">
    <block>
        123
        <input ng-model="var">
    </block>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('components', []).directive('block',function(){
    return{
        scope:false,
        replace:true,
        restrict:"E",
        transclude:true,
        template:'<div class="block" ng-transclude></div>',
        link:function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl){

        }
    }
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.ng-scope{
  border:1px solid red;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is actually expected behavior as stated here (ng-transclude create a child scope): https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1056
and discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/45jNmQucSCE/hL8x48-JfZIJ

You can workaround this by setting a member on an object in the scope (obj.var) like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rdarder/pnSNj/10/

Comment: Thanks. I made a more simple example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHLzK/5/).But is that a bug or is it a feature?

Comment: It's normal behavior for child scopes (they inherit by prototype from the parent scope, meaning that you can read from the parent scope, but as soon as you write, it's on the child scope - unless you use the obj on the parent scope workaroud), you could perhaps take a look at the source code of the ng-transclude directive, copy it and make your own with a scope: false option.

Comment: The issues comes up again if I start using transclude set as `element`. Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work now. Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bv1kFQtzdVzsasHTUrgf?p=preview

Comment: Why does setting a member on an object get around the fact that the nested template has it's own scope?

Comment: More clearly, how does the nested template have access to the parent scope without calling $scope.$parent?

Comment: Look up `javascript prototype inheritance`, it's very important if you want a deep understanding of javascript and in this case angular scopes inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not recommended by the Angular team, another workaround is to explicitly call the $parent scope within the transcluded portion:

```
<div ng-app="components">
    <input ng-model="var">
    <block>
        123
        <input ng-model="$parent.var">
    </block>
</div>
```