# Using `ng-model` within a transcluded directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is there anyway I can use use `ng-model` within a transclusion of a directive?

I have posted the code here: http://plunker.no.de/edit/XWAUp7?live=preview

I look forward to somebody to give me advice.

Comment: It's related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629151/angulajs-directive-transclude-scope-false/12629786#12629786

Comment: Thank you @Guillaume86. That works. Should I remove this topic?

Comment: No problem, yes I guess you can delete it since it's a duplicate

Comment: +1 Guillaume, here and in your actual answer. I answered before I saw your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're passing around a primitive type. If you use a reference type, like an object or an array, it will work a lot better. I've changed your plunk here [this demo](http://plunker.no.de/edit/OKjvrv)

Notice I had to pass an object into fOuter to make it work. Likewise, on fInner, if the primitive is the child of an object, it works both ways.

EDIT: Looks like Guillaume86 answered in the comments. Same answer, really.